# Can someone hack printer/photocopiers or buy printers/photocopiers that doesn't obey EURion constellation security measure

Tags: printers, watermarking

I'm not into counterfeiting. There was a debate.., so I decided to go deeper with curiosity.

EURion constellation is a pattern incorporated into banknotes. So photocopiers and printers if they obey the rule will not copy/print your banknote.

My question: if you buy, for example, a modern Xerox [photocopiers](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/eurion.pdf) it will refuse to copy the banknote with Eurion constellation. Can a hacker modify the firmware the photocopier to disable this feature?

Comment: Question #1: Probably. Question #2: Probably. Your first question is very broad and your second question does not really belong on this page. Could you narrow your first question down to a specific problem?

Comment: Doesn't the printer use authenticated firmware?

Comment: @TomK. actually, the questions complete each other. Assume that you cannot buy a printer without EURion, can someone hack it? Or they have good countermeasures against the hackers.

Comment: You say "*the* printer", but what printers are we talking about? What models? What vendors? You really have to give us some more information here.

Comment: That is the problem. I can give the list of the printers from EFF's site. But my question is a general. If you can provide a link for any of them it will be fine. I'm show it as an evidence to my debate.

Comment: Just add any specifics to your question that you can. For instance what exactly is the [EURion constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation)? Which printers (supposedly) recognize this constellation? What would you understand as "disable this feature"? etc.